# Javascript: How to iterate through log files

Tags: javascript

I have a .log file which is just lines of objects called `store_data.log` :

```
{"name": "Fred", "id": 31323, "favorited": false}
{"name": "Chris", "id": 33123, "favorited": true}
{"name": "Mike", "id": 33223, "favorited": true}
```

There is a corresponding file with it called `store_data.json` which contains the log file path:

```
{
    "log_path": "/intua/store_data.log"
}
```

In my JS file, I want to make a function that takes the path and iterates through the log info but I'm not sure where to start here since the log file is not in a format I know how to use.

Comment: `contents.split(/\r\n|\n/).forEach(itm => console.log(JSON.parse(itm)))`

Comment: Are you using node for this? Streaming to `Readline` might be a nice, memory-friendly, way to process these if the log files are large.

Comment: @MarkMeyer no, was told just by coworker just to make a function that takes the log path, which is located in the json file, and then iterate through the log file contents.  They are rather small files

Comment: @user10108817 how are you retrieving the contents of *"/intua/store_data.log"*?

Comment: that's what I'm trying to figure out as well.  He wants me to pass in the log path into the function that comes from the json file

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @DavidAngulo no, no Jquery used

Comment: I have the path passed into the function..i just dont know how to read the contents from that path and then iterate through

Comment: @user10108817 please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First read your file, split with '\n', and then iteratelly parse it.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('store_data.json'); // load config,

const logPath = config.log_path;

(async() => {
    const data = await fs.readFileSync(logPath, 'utf-8');
    const logs = data.split('\n');

    Array.from(logs).forEach(logString => {
        const log = JSON.parse(logString);
        console.log(log); // Your log here.
    })
})();
```

BTW, if your log file is large, readline or stream would be better.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var store_data_json_path = '/path/to/store_data.json'; //your store_data.json location

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET', store_data_json_path, false); //this will access the store_data.json data
xmlhttp.send();

var store_data_json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
var store_data_log_path;

store_data_log_path = store_data_json.log_path; //this will retrieve log_path from store_data.json

var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp2.open('GET', store_data_log_path, false); //this will access the store_data.log data
xmlhttp2.send();

var store_data_log_text = "[" + xmlhttp2.responseText + "]"; //this will add brackets that will make your string a valid json format
store_data_log_text = store_data_log_text.replace(/}/g, "},"); //will replace all } with }, to make it a valid JSON
store_data_log_text = store_data_log_text.replace(/,([^,]*)$/,"$1"); //will remove the last instance of , to make it a valid json

var store_data_log = JSON.parse(store_data_log_text); //we will convert the string to JSON

for(i in store_data_log) { //we will iterate to store_data.log
  console.log(store_data_log[i].name);
  console.log(store_data_log[i].id);
  console.log(store_data_log[i].favorited);
}
</script>
```